# Entropy change of an ideal gas undergoing adiabatic expansion into vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

For the adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas into an empty chamber, I am told that the entropy change of the system is not zero, and that the entropy change of the surroundings is zero.

But if the expansion is adiabatic, then it should be isentropic, so should not the entropy change of the system be zero? And how can you infer anything about the change in the surroundings?

Comment: What makes you think that the entropy change of the system should be zero?  Do the surroundings know that anything even happened inside the container?